# Create generic List<T> with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class with a property `IEnumerable<T>`. How do I make a generic method that creates a new `List<T>` and assigns that property?

```
IList list = property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
    .MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments())
    .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
```

I dont know where is `T` type can be anything

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you not just use `IEnumerable.ToList()`

Comment: What exactly are you tring to do, create a `List<T>` form `IEnumerable<T>`??

Comment: i need create a empty list with the type of the property

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you know the property name, and you know it is an `IEnumerable<T>` then this function will set it to a list of corresponding type:

```
public void AssignListProperty(Object obj, String propName)
{
  var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
  var listType = typeof(List<>);
  var genericArgs = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
  var concreteType = listType.MakeGenericType(genericArgs);
  var newList = Activator.CreateInstance(concreteType);
  prop.SetValue(obj, newList);
}
```

Please note this method does no type checking, or error handling. I leave that as an exercise to the user.

Comment: I had completely forgotten Activator.CreateInstance, error handling is done ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<int> Func()
        {
            yield return 1;
            yield return 2;
            yield return 3;
        }

        static List<int> MakeList()
        {
            return (List<int>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<int>), Func());
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach(int i in MakeList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `Func().ToList()`

Comment: Where is T? Is is not generic.