# Instantiate a generic collection using a Type argument

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

How can I instantiate a `List<Foo>` or `List<Bar>` at runtime by providing the System.Type value to a constructor?  This question has to be answered many times but I can't find it.

Ultimately, I want to make an extension method like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CreateEnumerable<T>(this System.Collections.IEnumerable list, Type type){
    var stuff = something;

    // magic happens to stuff where stuff becomes an IEnumerable<T> and T is of type 'type'

    return stuff as IEnumerable<T>;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create generic List<T> with reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888075/create-generic-listt-with-reflection)

Comment: That answer is close, but I don't want it linked to a property.  It may be that my understanding of the problem is what is actually the problem.

Comment: The actual instantiation of the generic list happens at `Activator.CreateInstance`; what you do with it from there is up to you, including `return newObject as IEnumerable<T>`; the trick is setting up the generic parameters bit correctly with your type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify the parameter of `List<>` at runtime using reflection and the [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) method.

```
var typeParam = typeof(Foo);
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeParam);
```

And then instantiate it using the [`Activator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) class

```
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

However, if all you're trying to do is turn an `IEnumerable` into an `IEnumerable<T>`, Linq already has methods ([`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) and [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)) to do this:

```
IEnumerable untypedList = ...

var foos = untypedList.Cast<Foo>(); // May throw InvalidCastException
var bars = untypedList.OfType<Bar>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your extension method is already generic. Just call the constructor.

```
var list = new List<T>();
```

If you want to convert a nongeneric IEnumerable to a generic one, there are already methods for that in System.Linq.

```
return list.Cast<T>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't logically make the `Type type` parameter match the `< T >` generic argument.

The extension method must return the non-generic `IEnumerable`.

It is possible to make it so as that this syntactical `IEnumerable` will in fact
(at runtime) hold a generic `IEnumerable < That particular type >`
but the user programmer which executes your extension method must
make an assumption, a check and a forced cast.

Beware that you might end up with `InvalidCastException` if you go down this route
and the user programmer isn't aware of things :).

Here it goes:

```
public static class SomeExtensions {

    private static readonly MethodInfo methodDefOf_PrivateHelper = typeof(SomeExtensions)
        .GetMethod("PrivateHelper", 
                   BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, 
                   Type.DefaultBinder, 
                   new [] { typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable) }, 
                   null);

    private static IEnumerable<T> PrivateHelper<T>(System.Collections.IEnumerable @this){
        foreach (var @object in @this)
            yield return (T)@object; // right here is were you can get the cast exception
    }

    public static System.Collections.IEnumerable DynamicCast(
        this System.Collections.IEnumerable @this,
        Type elementType
    ) {
        MethodInfo particularizedMethod = SomeExtensions.methodDefOf_PrivateHelper
            .MakeGenericMethod(elementType);

        object result = particularizedMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { @this });
        return result as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
    }


}
```

And here's how you could use that:

```
object[] someObjects = new object[] { "one", "two", "three" };
IEnumerable implicitlyCastedToEnumerable = someObjects;

Type unknownType = (DateTime.Now.Hour > 14) ? typeof(string) : typeof(int);

IEnumerable apparentlyNothingHappenedHere 
    = implicitlyCastedToEnumerable.DynamicCast(unknownType);

// if it's not after 14:00, then an exception would've jumped over this line and
// straight out the exit bracket or into some catch clause

// it it's after 14:00, then the apparentlyNothingHappenedHere enumerable can do this:
IEnumerable<string> asStrings = (IEnumerable<string>)apparentlyNothingHappenedHere;

// whereas the earlier would've cause a cast exception at runtime
IEnumerable<string> notGoingToHappen = (IEnumerable<string>)implicitlyCastedToEnumerable;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CreateEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable list, Type type) {
    var stuff=something;

    var temp=stuff;
    stuff=Array.CreateInstance(type, count) as T[]; 
    // copy elements to stuff
    return stuff as IEnumerable<T>;
}
```

However, nothing is guaranteed that `T` is of type `type`. Look at the signature of `CreateEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CreateEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable list, Type type)
```

There is no `T` from the argument to infer which generic method to invoke, that is, it's required to specify a type parameter when you wish to call it. I would think that `T` is redundant, and rather

```
public static IEnumerable CreateEnumerable(this IEnumerable list, Type type) {
    var stuff=something;

    var temp=stuff;
    stuff=Array.CreateInstance(type, count);
    // copy elements to stuff
    return stuff as IEnumerable;
}
```

Note that I have no idea of the `count` you would like to have.